# Versioning objects in Java application

Tags: java, spring-boot, versioning

I have this variable in my Java application:

```
@Pattern(
    regexp = "^[a-zA-Z0-9-]{4,}$",
    message =
        "Alphanumeric characters and '-' only allowed. Must be at least four characters long.",
    groups = FormatCheck.class)
private String registration;
```

This is fine as I currently have one client which sends a registration that matches the pattern. In the future I could potentially have multiple clients, all which have their own registration patterns. Is it possible to in some way version the variable or the pattern so that all my clients could use the same variable but each could validate against a different pattern?  I'd like to avoid creating new variables for each client that uses its own pattern.

Comment: Why? Why is it up to the client which pattern is valid, as opposed to the server? What is the problem with creating new variables for each client? And if it is, why not allow the most general pattern for all clients? I guess I don't understand the problem.

Comment: That was an example. Maybe not a great one. I basically want a facility where the input could change without having to coordinate updates or releases with clients. Think the solution is to introduce some form of versioning. Examples of things that could change in the input are things like validation or location of an object. Possibly even the type in some rarer cases.

Answer (score 0):

Since annotations are evaluated at compilation, you can't use a runtime variable as a parameter since during compilation the runtime variables don't already have values.

In your case, you will most likely need to create a getter/setter method that will do the pattern matching logic and return null or throw an exception if it fails